# Drawn polygons in QGIS (3.2) are not accurate in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: qgis, polygon, arcgis-online

I am drawing polygons in QGIS (see figure 1), but when I import the shapefile to ArcGIS Online, it does not look like what it is on QGIS (see figure 2). Instead of being an intricate polygon, its all clunky and jagged. What am I doing wrong?

The projections are WGS-84 3857

Figure 1: Shapefile in QGIS

[image]

Figure 2: Shapefile in ArcGIS Online

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. This is a case where more details are necessary, and a picture would be priceless. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: Your polygons in the image from arcgis online have fewer nodes than in QGIS. I wonder if ArcGIS is simplifying the layer when you upload it. That might be a setting you can change in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a possible solution:
Publish layer as feature, so that polygons are not simplified in Web Display

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-features.htm